# How to create provision profile for an existing app iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile

I've developed an app and created a provisioning profile in apple's member centre and downloaded, installed then submitted app to App Store. Then after my mac is formatted and I've lost the profile and the keychain access.

Now my development is shifted to another mac where I tried to install that provisioning profile which is already there in member centre but it asked me to revoke the thing so I revoked and deleted it. now I lost provisioning profile.

The only thing I've is App Store Id, newly created provisioning profiles are actually not accepted now I don't why it says no matching provisioning profiles exist? what to do? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you created the provisioning profile with the app id?

Comment: yep, I've created distribution certificate and downloaded it installed and created provisioning and insalled

Comment: Btw, did you add your Developer account in the Xcode preferences area. then, it will show all the provisioning files in the preference tab itself. no need to download them externally

Comment: oh Its there in that Xcode preferences also, and installed locally also, do I need to remove my account from all other macs

Comment: No, not needed. did you try with restarting Xcode. Actually, I got similar kind of problem in Xcode6, but didn't get on Xcode 7.

Comment: try to create an another certificate. it will resolve the issue instead spending time in fixing. you have already revoked it fine. create an another certificate with the app id what you have given to your app. the create one provisioning profile for that. it will resolve the issue. 
Hint. if you are generating a certificate , send it to you with private key via email. if you ever lost. you can get it form your email.

Comment: Are you sure that the app ID you are building matches exactly (capitalization also) the app ID for which you created the profile?  Open the provisioning profile in TextEdit and ensure that the app ID is correct by searching for `<key>application-identifier</key>`

Answer (score 0):

Xcode now manages provisioning profiles quite easily as long as you provide it with your Apple IDs.

Select `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts`, then click on the bottom left "+" and "Add Apple ID". Provide your developer App ID credentials.

Now select `YOUR PROJECT > General > Identity` and click on "Fix" to get Xcode to generate your provisioning profile.

You can also check out your current signing identities and provisioning profiles directly on `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > YOUR TEAM > View Details`